# While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.osx.x86_64): config.push.js:2:7: Unexpected token (2:7)

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-cloud-messaging, ecmascript-6

Please, I kept receiving error message when I tried to run a meteor app I am designing. I named the problematic code config.push.js and it is listed as followed:

```
{
  "gcm": {
"apiKey": "uuuuuyyytttrrreeewwwdddfffggg",
"projectNumber": 000000000000
},
"production": false,
"badge": true,
"sound": true,
"alert": true,
"vibrate": true
}
```

I am using meteor@1.3.3

The following is the error message I received:

```
While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.osx.x86_64):
config.push.js:2:7: Unexpected token (2:7)
```

The Unexpected token (2:7) refers to this line:

```
"gcm": {
```

This error message began to appear after I updated to meteor 1.3.3
Meanwhile, I know it has to do with syntax that relates to ECMAScript 6 but I do not know how to rewrite that code to eliminate the error.

Thanks for your anticipated help.

Comment: Is `000000000000` just a placeholder or is it the actual value in your code? Leading 0s are invalid in JSON.

Comment: I just coined it, because I didn't want to show my real project number. Thanks.

Comment: If the content is JSON, why have you named the file `.js`? That seems like the cause of the error.